# Add button to ribbon by template

Tags: content-editor

I need to add a new button on the ribbon in ContentEditor for a specific template. It follows the instructions:
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_what39s_new/posts/adding-a-custom-button-to-the-ribbon
The problem is the lack of information how I can associate such an operation with the template. This means: the new part of the menu will be shown, e.g. for the media folder, and for other templates it will not appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `QueryState` method like that:

```
public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
{
  var item = context.Items[0];

  if (item.TemplateID != MyTemplateId)
    return CommandState.Hidden;

  return base.QueryState(context);
}
```

**EDIT**

After OP's question. There is no additional configuration needed. It's just one more method you need to override. So if you copied code from the link you added in your question and wrote your custom code in `Execute` method, you need to do the same with `QueryState` method:

```
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
using System;

namespace Sc.Int.MiniBizz.Customaztion
{
    class MBCustomButtonImport : Command
    {
        public override void Execute (CommandContext context)
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Testing my button");
        }
        
        public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
          var item = context.Items[0];

          if (item.TemplateID != MyTemplateId)
            return CommandState.Hidden;

          return base.QueryState(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks interesting. Can you tell where the configuration is added to this item?

Comment: @JanNowak no configuration, you need to override QueryState the same way you did the Execute method in the same class of your command.

Comment: @JanNowak answer updated

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works great. I have one more question, is there any documentation that contains information about the methods and the possibility of writing them? Unfortunately, I do not see anything like that in the official documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any official documentation. But there are plenty of blog posts which are helpful in cases like this one.